# virtual centOS 6.2 - How to share /var/www using Samba

Tags: linux, apache, centos, samba

I have Windows XP, installed VirtualBox, and have now a centOS virtual machine.
I am sharing folders between the two machines using Samba.

I have successfully accessed shared folders in the Home directory.
My problem now is how do I access /var/www? (I have exactly the same setting with home directories in smb.conf except path).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a problem related to /var/www being owned by `root`, or `apache` user, and not accessible to other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add such section to the smb.conf:

```
[www]
   comment = Web Root Dir
   path = /var/www
   valid users = user
   public = no
   writable = yes
   printable = no
```

User `user` must exist in the system and in Samba (added by `smbpasswd -a user`). Of course you can use other username.

Check if your user `user` can access this filesystem in Linux (without samba). If it can't you must give him access rights in Linux.

Comment: I actually tried it but I still got the error message as above. (SEE EDIT)

Comment: Check if your user user can access this filesystem in Linux (without samba)